# uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::GravatarHelper when installing AgileDwarf plugin on Redmine 3.3

Tags: ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm clone plugin in `/usr/share/redmine/lib/plugins` from `git clone` https://github.com/iRessources/AgileDwarf . When i execute in directory `/usr/share/redmine` `bundle install --without development test --no-deployment` Output:

> Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed,
>   and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all
>   non-root users on this machine. Using rake 10.5.0 Using i18n 0.7.0
>   Using json 2.0.1 Using minitest 5.9.0 Using thread_safe 0.3.5 Using
>   builder 3.2.2 Using erubis 2.7.0 Using nokogiri 1.6.8.1 Using rack
>   1.6.4 Using mime-types 2.6.1 Using arel 6.0.3 Using addressable 2.4.0 Using coderay 1.1.1 Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.0 Using htmlentities
>   4.3.3 Using thor 0.19.1 Using mimemagic 0.3.0 Using net-ldap 0.12.1 Using pg 0.18.4 Using ruby-openid 2.7.0 Using bundler 1.13.6 Using
>   rbpdf-font 1.19.0 Using redcarpet 3.3.4 Using request_store 1.3.0
>   Using rmagick 2.16.0 Using tzinfo 1.2.2 Using loofah 2.0.3 Using
>   rack-test 0.6.3 Using mail 2.6.4 Using css_parser 1.3.6 Using
>   sprockets 3.7.0 Using rack-openid 1.4.2 Using rbpdf 1.19.0 Using
>   activesupport 4.2.7.1 Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3 Using roadie
>   3.1.1 Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3 Using globalid 0.3.6 Using activemodel 4.2.7.1 Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6 Using
>   activejob 4.2.7.1 Using activerecord 4.2.7.1 Using
>   protected_attributes 1.1.3 Using actionview 4.2.7.1 Using actionpack
>   4.2.7.1 Using actionmailer 4.2.7.1 Using actionpack-action_caching 1.1.1 Using actionpack-xml_parser 1.0.2 Using railties 4.2.7.1 Using sprockets-rails 2.3.2 Using jquery-rails 4.2.1 Using roadie-rails
>   1.1.0 Using rails 4.2.7.1 Bundle complete! 23 Gemfile dependencies, 53 gems now installed. Gems in the groups development and test were not
>   installed. Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is
>   installed.

Next `bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=AgileDwarf RAILS_ENV=production`. Output

> rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant
>   ApplicationHelper::GravatarHelper
>   /usr/share/redmine/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:26:in
>   `<module:ApplicationHelper>'
>   /usr/share/redmine/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:23:in`'
>   /usr/share/redmine/lib/redmine/hook/view_listener.rb:34:in
>   `<class:ViewListener>'
>   /usr/share/redmine/lib/redmine/hook/view_listener.rb:22:in`
>   '
>   /usr/share/redmine/lib/redmine/hook/view_listener.rb:19:in
>   `<module:Redmine>'
>   /usr/share/redmine/lib/redmine/hook/view_listener.rb:18:in`' /usr/share/redmine/lib/redmine.rb:66:in `<top
>   (required)>' /usr/share/redmine/lib/plugins/AgileDwarf/init.rb:1:in`
>   block in '
>   /usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in `eval'
>   /usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:12:in`block
>   in '
>   /usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in `each'
>   /usr/share/redmine/config/initializers/00-core_plugins.rb:2:in`' /usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top
>   (required)>' /usr/share/redmine/lib/tasks/redmine.rake:52:in`block (2
>   levels) in ' Tasks: TOP => redmine:plugins:migrate =>
>   environment (See full trace by running task with --trace)

When i'm restart apache2. And on the site wrote an error:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it
>   shortly. Information for the administrator of this website
>
> The Phusion Passenger application server encountered an error while
>   starting your web application. Because you are running this web
>   application in staging or production mode, the details of the error
>   have been omitted from this web page for security reasons.
>
> Please read the Passenger log file to find the details of the error.
>
> Alternatively, you can turn on the "friendly error pages" feature (see
>   below), which will make Phusion Passenger show many details about the
>   error right in the browser.
>
> To turn on friendly error pages:

Redmine version:

> Environment:   Redmine version                3.3.1.stable   Ruby
>   version                   2.3.3-p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
>   Rails version                  4.2.7.1   Environment
>   production   Database adapter               PostgreSQL SCM:   Git
>   2.11.0   Filesystem                      Redmine plugins:   no plugin installed

Comment: When pasting log output, please don't paste it as a quotation but use code formatting instead (paste them with 4 spaces at the start of each line). The way you have pasted it here, the logs are about unreadable since all line-breaks were removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my mistake, just need create folder `plugins` in `usr/share/redmine/` and deploy they here. If deploy plugins in /`usr/share/redmine/lib/plugins` this returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

The [AgileDwarf plugin](https://github.com/iRessources/AgileDwarf) seems to be unmaintained since about 5 years. Judging from the [various filled issues](https://github.com/iRessources/AgileDwarf/issues) on the project, it appears the plugin is not compatible with Redmine 3.x. There appear to be multiple issues in all layers of the plugin preventing its use in current Redmine versions.

You might be able to find a fork of the plugin where someone provides support for Redmine 3.x.

Alternatively (and this is probably the better option going forward), you could find a different plugin for agile issue management, e.g. [RedmineUP's agile plugin](https://www.redmineup.com/pages/plugins/agile).

Comment: Now I tried RedmineUP's agile plugin. issued the same error(

Comment: You also need to remove the AgileDwarf plugin.